# Diacritics alphabetical ordering in C#

Tags: c#, list, diacritics

I want to know how do you perform a reliable alphabetical ordering (for a listbox) of people's full names with the diacritics of the language in C sharp?

Thanks in advance.

***Q***: So you just want to treat diacritics as the "original" letter? (eg: João is the same as Joao)? – NullUserException

***A***: I want to treat them as they should be treated in the language I define, respecting the rules of alphabetical ordering that people apply everyday. I'm sure it's written in the grammars of each language. Thanks. – Queops

Comment: So you just want to treat diacritics as the "original" letter? (eg:  João is the same as Joao)?

Comment: It's alphabetical order rather than grammar, but yes most alphabetic languages have an order for these things if they use diacritics heavily. Some informal, some formal, and some with more than one formal (quite a few have a dictionary sort for words but a "telephone directory" sort for names that differs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This MSDN article should give you what you need: [Comparing and Sorting Data for a Specific Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7zyyk0c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). It describes culture sensitive comparison, sorting, and normalization, with code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)` to normalize a string `s`, separating accented characters into unaccented characters followed by the accent symbol.  You can then use `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark` to identify accent characters `c` in the normalized `s`.  Given that, you can implement your own string comparison operator to place whatever ordering you need on accents.